# How to reduce the query execution time with full text search and huge data

Tags: sql-server

[image: Here is the structure of my table]

The table contains more than 3 million records and I need to apply a full text search query (actually a very huge query).
here is the query and it's response:

```
select Top 10 SerialNo, Registrationno,Status,MarkIdentification,OwnerName,Casefilestatementstext from Trademark where 
(MarkIdentification LIKE '% CALIDOUBLE %' 
OR MarkIdentification LIKE 'CALIDOUBLE %' 
OR MarkIdentification LIKE 'CALIDOUBLEs %' 
OR MarkIdentification LIKE '% CALIDOUBLEs %' 
OR MarkIdentification LIKE 'CALIDOUBLE''s %' 
OR MarkIdentification LIKE 'CALIDOUBLE''s%'  
OR MarkIdentification LIKE 'CALIDOUBLE' 
OR MarkIdentification LIKE '%-CALIDOUBLE' 
OR MarkIdentification LIKE '% CALIDOUBLE')  
AND ( 
USClassId like  '%001%' OR USClassId like  '%023%' OR USClassId like  '%027%' OR USClassId like  '%034%' 
OR USClassId like  '%038%' OR USClassId like  '%039%' OR USClassId like  '%045%' OR USClassId like  '%046%' 
OR USClassId like  '%047%' OR USClassId like  '%048%' OR USClassId like  '%100%' OR USClassId like  '%101%' 
OR USClassId like  '%104%' OR USClassId like  '%105%' OR USClassId like  '%107%' ) 
AND ((Casefilestatementstext like '%Ale%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Ales%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Apron%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Aprons%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Barbeque%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Barbeques%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Beany%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Beanies%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Beer%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Beers%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Beverage%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Beverages%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Blouse%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Blouses%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Bologna%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Bolognas%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Boot%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Boots%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Bread%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Breads%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Burger%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Burgers%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Cake%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Cakes%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Candy%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Candies%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Cap%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Caps%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Catsup%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Catsups%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Cattle%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Cattle%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Cheese%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Cheese%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Clock%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Clocks%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Coat%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Coats%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Coffee%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Coffees%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Collar%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Collars%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Cuff%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Cuffs%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Dress%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Dresses%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Espresso%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Espressoes%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Falafel%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Falafels%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Fish%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Fish%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Flour%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Flours%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Food%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Foods%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Frankfurter%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Frankfurters%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Ham%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Hams%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Hamburger%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Hamburgers%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Hat%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Hats%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Jacket%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Jackets%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Jean%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Jeans%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Magazine%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Magazines%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Marinade%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Marinades%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Meatball%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Meatballs%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Milk%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Milk%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Mustard%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Mustards%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pajama%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pajamas%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pant%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pants%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pasta%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pastas%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pecan%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pecans%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pepperoni%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pepperonis%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pickle%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pickles%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pie%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pies%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pizza%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Pizzas%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Poultry%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Poultries%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Rice%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Rice%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Roast%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Roasts%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Roll%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Rolls%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Salami%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Salamis%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Salsa%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Salsas%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Sandwich%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Sandwiches%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Sauce%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Sauces%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Sausage%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Sausages%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Seasoning%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Seasonings%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Shirt%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Shirts%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Short%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Shorts%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Slack%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Slacks%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Smoothy%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Smoothies%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Spice%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Spices%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Stout%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Stouts%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Sugar%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Sugars%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Suit%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Suits%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Sweater%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Sweaters%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Sweatshirt%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Sweatshirts%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Syrup%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Syrups%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Tie%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Ties%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Trouser%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Trousers%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%T-shirts%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%T-shirts%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Underwear%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Underwears%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Watch%') 
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Watches%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Wine%')
OR(Casefilestatementstext like '%Wines%') 
) 
AND (
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Bakery,good), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Bakeries,good), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Bakery,goods), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Bakeries,goods), 6)'))  
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Bean,garbanzo,processed), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beans,garbanzo,processed), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Bean,garbanzoes,processed), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beans,garbanzoes,processed), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Bean,garbanzo,processeds), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beans,garbanzo,processeds), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Bean,garbanzoes,processeds), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beans,garbanzoes,processeds), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((beauty,contest), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((beauties,contest), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((beauty,contests), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((beauties,contests), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beef,patty), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beef,patty), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beef,patties), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beef,patties), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beef,minced), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beef,minced), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beef,minceds), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beef,minceds), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beef,processed), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beef,processed), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beef,processeds), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beef,processeds), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((beverage,station), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((beverages,station), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((beverage,stations), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((beverages,stations), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beverage,maltless), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beverages,maltless), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beverage,maltlesses), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beverages,maltlesses), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beverage,non-alcoholic), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beverages,non-alcoholic), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beverage,non-alcoholic), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Beverages,non-alcoholic), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((boat,cruis), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((boats,cruis), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((boat,cruises), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((boats,cruises), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Bread,mix), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Breads,mix), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Bread,mixes), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Breads,mixes), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Bread,pocket), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Breads,pocket), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Bread,pockets), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Breads,pockets), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Cake,mix), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Cakes,mix), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Cake,mixes), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Cakes,mixes), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((catering,beverage), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((caterings,beverage), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((catering,beverage), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((caterings,beverage), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((catering,beverages), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((caterings,beverages), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((catering,beverages), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((caterings,beverages), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((catering,food), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((caterings,food), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((catering,food), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((caterings,food), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((catering,foods), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((caterings,foods), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((catering,foods), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((caterings,foods), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Chicken,prepared), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Chickens,prepared), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Chicken,prepareds), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Chickens,prepareds), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Chickpea,processed), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Chickpeas,processed), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Chickpea,processeds), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Chickpeas,processeds), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((coffee,certification), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((coffees,certification), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((coffee,certifications), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((coffees,certifications), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((coffee,shop), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((coffees,shop), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((coffee,shops), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((coffees,shops), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((concession,stand), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((concessions,stand), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((concession,stands), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((concessions,stands), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((convenience,store), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((conveniences,store), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((convenience,stores), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((conveniences,stores), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((cooking,cours), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((cookings,cours), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((cooking,courses), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((cookings,courses), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((cooking,lecture), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((cookings,lecture), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((cooking,lectures), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((cookings,lectures), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Cottage,cheese), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Cottages,cheese), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Cottage,cheeses), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Cottages,cheeses), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Custard,frozen), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Custards,frozen), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Custard,frozens), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Custards,frozens), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,concert,production), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,concert,production), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,concert,production), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,concert,production), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,concerts,production), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,concerts,production), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,concerts,production), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,concerts,production), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,concert,productions), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,concert,productions), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,concert,productions), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,concert,productions), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,concerts,productions), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,concerts,productions), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,concerts,productions), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,concerts,productions), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,firework), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,firework), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,firework), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,firework), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,fireworks), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,fireworks), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,fireworks), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,fireworks), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,hosting,party), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,hosting,party), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,hosting,party), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,hosting,party), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,hostings,party), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,hostings,party), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,hostings,party), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,hostings,party), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,hosting,parties), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,hosting,parties), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,hosting,parties), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,hosting,parties), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,hostings,parties), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,hostings,parties), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainment,hostings,parties), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((entertainments,hostings,parties), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fish,glaze), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fish,glaze), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fish,glazes), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fish,glazes), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fish,rub,dry), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fish,rub,dry), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fish,rubs,dry), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fish,rubs,dry), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fish,rub,dries), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fish,rub,dries), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fish,rubs,dries), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fish,rubs,dries), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((food,delivery), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((foods,delivery), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((food,deliveries), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((foods,deliveries), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((food,preparation), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((foods,preparation), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((food,preparations), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((foods,preparations), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Food,product), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Foods,product), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Food,products), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Foods,products), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Food,product,Chinese), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Foods,product,Chinese), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Food,products,Chinese), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Foods,products,Chinese), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Food,product,Chinese), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Foods,product,Chinese), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Food,products,Chinese), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Foods,products,Chinese), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Food,product,frozen), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Foods,product,frozen), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Food,products,frozen), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Foods,products,frozen), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Food,product,frozens), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Foods,product,frozens), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Food,products,frozens), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Foods,products,frozens), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fruit,drink), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fruits,drink), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fruit,drinks), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fruits,drinks), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fryer,deep,fat), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fryers,deep,fat), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fryer,deeps,fat), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fryers,deeps,fat), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fryer,deep,fats), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fryers,deep,fats), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fryer,deeps,fats), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Fryers,deeps,fats), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((gourmet,shop,restaurant), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((gourmets,shop,restaurant), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((gourmet,shops,restaurant), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((gourmets,shops,restaurant), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((gourmet,shop,restaurants), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((gourmets,shop,restaurants), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((gourmet,shops,restaurants), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((gourmets,shops,restaurants), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Hot,dog), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Hots,dog), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Hot,dogs), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Hots,dogs), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((hotel,reservation), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((hotels,reservation), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((hotel,reservations), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((hotels,reservations), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,cream), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,cream), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,creams), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,creams), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,milk,bar), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,milk,bar), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,milk,bar), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,milk,bar), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,milk,bars), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,milk,bars), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,milk,bars), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,milk,bars), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,flavored,colored), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,flavored,colored), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,flavoreds,colored), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,flavoreds,colored), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,flavored,coloreds), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,flavored,coloreds), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,flavoreds,coloreds), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Ice,flavoreds,coloreds), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internet,shopping,meat), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internets,shopping,meat), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internet,shoppings,meat), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internets,shoppings,meat), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internet,shopping,meat), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internets,shopping,meat), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internet,shoppings,meat), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internets,shoppings,meat), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internet,shopping,meats), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internets,shopping,meats), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internet,shoppings,meats), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internets,shoppings,meats), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internet,shopping,meats), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internets,shopping,meats), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internet,shoppings,meats), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((internets,shoppings,meats), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((juice,bar), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((juices,bar), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((juice,bars), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((juices,bars), 6)')) 
/* 750 rows of same kind of full text search*/
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Tacoes,shell), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Taco,shells), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Tacoes,shells), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Top,tank), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Tops,tank), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Top,tanks), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Tops,tanks), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((travel,agency), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((travels,agency), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((travel,agencies), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((travels,agencies), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Vegetable,dried), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Vegetables,dried), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Vegetable,drieds), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Vegetables,drieds), 6)')) 
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Waffle,mix), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Waffles,mix), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Waffle,mixes), 6)'))
OR( CONTAINS(Casefilestatementstext,'NEAR((Waffles,mixes), 6)'))
  )
Order by Registrationno desc, SerialNo desc
```

Here is the response of the query:

[image: Result of the query]

How can I get the fast result with either optimize the query or Change the table structure?

Comment: `OR` statement increase your query execution time , try to use `IN` instead of `OR`. Check this link , how to optimize qury.:http://www.cocomore.com/blog/mysql-query-optimization

Comment: That's **NOT** a full-text query. That's a wild card query, and it's bad because you can't use indexes with this kind of wildcard query. A real full-text query uses a special full text index and different syntax (the `CONTAINS()` keyword). Also, why have both `Casefilestatementstext like '%Ale%'` and `Casefilestatementstext like '%Ales%'` The former implies the later. Same for `Beverage` and `Beverages`, `Blouse` and `Blouses`, etc. Using both just makes it slower.

Comment: Thanks Joel, but what about Baby and Babies? and If you see the query closer, you can find "the CONTAINS() keyword". So, pls read post carefully before comment.

Comment: Yes Baby and Babies is a valid special case but `%Ale%` and `%Ales%` is _still_ not a valid case. Then the question is: why use wildcard queries _at all_  if you have a fulltext index?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a "Processed" BIT field to the Trademark table, with a default of 0, and then make a "hash table" that contains the TrademarkID column as a foreign key into the Trademark table and a series of Bit fields that indicate whether a particular item in that monster WHERE clause evaluates to TRUE.  Update that hash table with an overnight scheduled job which runs against every record with a Processed flag of 0, and then set each record's Processed flag to 1 after it has been processed.  Then do your searches against that, and UNION the results with your current query that only looks at records where Processed is 0.

In fact, you could also keep this hash table up-to-date via INSERT and UPDATE triggers (this thought occurred to me while driving to work).  I typically don't use triggers, but if you're comfortable with them then that would be another option, and it would simplify the query logic.

Also, some of the LIKE comparisons on CALIDOUBLE are redundant, in that if one is true then the other must be true as well, and you can replace any LIKE that has no wildcards with "=", which will perform better.  However, a bunch of LIKE statements combined by OR is going to be slow, regardless.

Here are some additional thoughts on how to approach this - I hope it makes my idea clearer:

Add a field to the TradeMark table that indicates whether that record needs to be hashed.  I'll call it "NeedsHashed" in my example.

Whenever a TradeMark record is inserted or updated, set "NeedsHashed" to "1".  Probably use a trigger for that.

Create a table called TradeMarkHash.  I'll sketch out a few rows to give you the idea

```
Create Table TradeMarkHash
(
    TradeMarkID BigInt not null         -- this is the PK on this table, as well
    , Calidouble bit
    , USClassID bit
    , CaseFileAle bit
    , CaseFileNearBakeryGood bit
    -- etc.
)
```

Next, create a procedure that runs every night on an agent job.  This procedure:

1. selects every record with a NeedHashed value of "1"
2. applies the logic from each section of that WHERE clause to calculate the corresponding flag:

   - if any of the LIKE comparisons on Calidouble are true, then set TradeMarkHash.Calidouble to "1"
   - If the USCLassID is one of the specified values, set TradeMarkHash.USClassID to "1"
   - If the Casefilestatementstext is like '%Ale%' or like '%Ales%' set TradeMarkHash.CaseFileAle to "1"
   - If the Casefilestatementstext satisfies any of the NEAR comparisons for "bakery/bakeries" and "good/goods", set TradeMarkHash.CaseFileNearBakeryGood to "1"
   - etc.
3. sets TradeMark.NeedHashed to "0"

Note, these are "upserts" - if a record for the given TradeMarkID exists, it's an update; if not, it's an insert.  Also, look for locations to streamline these comparisons - for example, anything that is LIKE '%Ale%" will be LIKE '%Ales%', as well

Now, when you do a select, instead of finding records in the TradeMark table that match that monster LIKE for various 'Calidouble' permuations, you would do:

```
Select tm.<fields>
    From TradeMark as tm
        Inner Join TradeMarkHash as tmh
            on tm.TradeMarkID = tmh.TradeMarkID
    Where tmh.Calidouble = 1
    And tmh.USClassID = 1
    ... and whatever other conditions are appropriate
```

I expect that the above will be MUCH faster than the query you initially posted.  Essentially you're doing the WHERE logic ahead of time, during a period of low server load, and storing the results for later use.  However, as with all performance questions, you'll have to test.

Comment: If these records could change, I would add a pair of rowversion columns instead of a bit column, one that updates automatically and one you can set to match it during the overnight job. Of course, this also leaves you open to latency issues, where the index table has an old data.

Comment: Good point.  Another way to handle that would be to reset the Processed bit to 0 if its record changes.

Comment: Hello @Brian, I didn't get how a hash table will light weight my select query and how It will speed up the data retrieval. Can you please elaborate more? or any sample reference will be much helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I've expanded my initial answer with more details.  Let me know if you have any other questions..

Comment: It certainly is good approach to pre-calc all this stuff. However removing all the wildcard searches and using only the fulltext catalog should hopefully improve performance to the point where none of this is necessary.

Comment: Perhaps it would, @Nick.McDermaid (assuming, of course, that you can replace the wildcard searches and complex AND/OR logic with fulltext catalog searches.  Even if you do that, though, I would expect that caching the search logic at night and querying against flags will be faster still.

Comment: Maybe.. .we won't know unless he tries it. I'm not discounting your solution, it's just that the simplest solutions are the easiest to maintain.

Comment: True - as with all performance questions, the answer will involve "test it".  I've amended my answer accordingly.